# How to populate new html pages with xml data in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an RSS reader that fetches events with ajax. I want the user to be able to click the link of the event and have it transition to a new page with the details. Here is an example I found: http://jsfiddle.net/hellosze/t22QP/ I am have trouble understanding what is happening since I am rather new to jQuery so I was hoping someone code direct me as to what is happening. Thanks!

Here is how I extract the xml data and display it to a main page:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'categoryURL',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function (xml) {
        var data = [];
        $(xml).find("item:lt(40)").each(function () {
            var dateText = $(this).find("Date").text().toString();
            var eventDate = moment(dateText,"YYYY-MM-DD");
            var title = $(this).find("title").text();

            var region = dateText.substr(8).toUpperCase();
                if (region.length < 3) { region = "ALL"; }  

            var description = $(this).find("description").text();
            var dateDisplay = description.substr(0, description.indexOf(",")+6); //Parsed DATE from description
                  if (dateDisplay.length > 35) { dateDisplay = "See event for details"; }

            //var locationdisplay = description.substr(description.indexOf(",")+6,4); //Parsed the location from description
            var category = $(this).find("category").text();
            var linkUrl = $(this).find("link").text();
            var displayTitle = "<a href='" + linkUrl + "' target='_blank'>" + title + "</a>" 

            var item = {title: displayTitle, DateDecription: dateDisplay, Date: new Date(eventDate), Region: region,}
            data.push(item);

           // $('#feedContainer').append('<h3>'+displaytitle+'</h3><p>'+"Event Date: "+descriptdisplay+'</p><p>'+"Location: "+region+'</p');

        }); //END .each()

        data.sort(function (a, b) {
            a = new Date(a.Date);
            b = new Date(b.Date);
            return a>b ? -1 : a<b ? 1 : 0;
        });

        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
            $('#feedContainer').append('<h3>' + item.title + '</h3><p>' + "Event Date: " + item.DateDecription + '</p><p>' + "Location: " + item.Region + '</p');
        });
    } //END success fn
});
});
```

Comment: I reformatted your code/indenting and notice there is an extra closing brace set at end. Is that a typo?

Comment: Ah, Yes that is a typo! Thank you for catching that. I just pulled a snippet of my code in case anyone needed to view how I am displaying my data.